# "Reachability.h" "Reachability.m gives an Apple mach-o linker error while adding them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, reachability

I am creating an iPhone application, and I am using RestKit api to connect to the server. I am facing a problem whenever I add the `Reachability.m` and `Reachability.h` into the second `UIViewController` of the project. I tried making a new .m file in Xcode4 and now I get an Apple macho-linker (id) error on all tabst. I added it to the first `UIViewcontroller` it works normally, but when I try to add it to any other forms I receive this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by importing ONLY "Reachability.h" not "Reachability.h" and "Reachability.m"

Answer (score 5):

Have you added the `SystemsConfigurations.Framework` to your project? Apples reachability package requires the `SystemConfigurations.Framework` to be added before it can be used.

Also if you are using ARC (Automatic ReferenceCounting), ensure you have disabled ARC for that particular file. Do this by going to build phases, compile sources, then double clicking `Reachability.m` and entering **-fno-objc-arc** to disable ARC

Comment: yes i have added the SystemConfiguration Framework, and do i need to import it in the header?

also i have disabled the ARC, and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try adding CFNetwork.framework.